# How to add totals to stacked bars in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using a stacked column chart from amCharts. It add number labels to the portion of bars in the stacked bars.

How do also add totals of each bars on top of the stacks?

For example, if first column in the graph has five parititions as below:
Size (height) of first partition: 5
Size (height) of second partition: 11
Size (height) of third partition: 14
Size (height) of fourth partition: 20
Size (height) of fifth partition: 21

I get these labels right now. But, I also want a label on top of the first column (stacked bar) which says 71.
71 was obtained by adding 5, 11, 14, 20 and 21.

http://jsfiddle.net/jn2695pc/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "none",
    "legend": {
        "horizontalGap": 10,
        "maxColumns": 1,
        "position": "right",
        "useGraphSettings": true,
        "markerSize": 10
    },
    "dataProvider": [{
        "year": 2003,
        "europe": 2.5,
        "namerica": 2.5,
        "asia": 2.1,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.2,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "europe": 2.6,
        "namerica": 2.7,
        "asia": 2.2,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.3,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "europe": 2.8,
        "namerica": 2.9,
        "asia": 2.4,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.3,
        "africa": 0.1
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
        "axisAlpha": 0.3,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Europe",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "europe"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "North America",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "namerica"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Asia-Pacific",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "asia"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Latin America",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "lamerica"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Middle-East",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "meast"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[value]]",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": "Africa",
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        "valueField": "africa"
    }],
    "categoryField": "year",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    },
    "exportConfig":{
        "menuTop":"20px",
        "menuRight":"20px",
        "menuItems": [{
        "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
        "format": 'png'   
        }]  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part of your question, you can add the

`"titleText":"[[total]]"`

option to your `"valueAxes"`, ie:

```
"valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "regular",
        "axisAlpha": 0.3,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "totalText": "[[total]]"
    }],
```

http://www.amcharts.com/tips/using-categoryaxis-totaltext-display-total-value-stacked-chart/

That will show the totals at the top of each stack. As far adding the "this was obtained by" part... good luck.